# Deletar uma lista de dados no EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Eu tenho um método que deleta uma versão de um arquivo  de acordo com a versão do arquivo passado, 1 arquivo pode ter muitas versões, e eu queria apagar todas as versões, eu consegui apagar apenas 1 versão de um determinado arquivo.Mas quero apagar todas as versões de um determinado arquivo, vejam:

```
internal void ApagarArquivoVersao(Model.ArquivoVersao arquivoVersao)
    {
        using (var ctx = new TESTEntities())
        {
            var fileVer = ctx.ARQUIVO_VERSAO.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ARQUIVO_GUID == arquivoVersao.ARQUIVO_GUID);
            if (fileVer == null)
                throw new ArquivoException("Arquivo não encontrado");

            ctx.Entry(fileVer).State = System.Data.EntityState.Deleted;
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

O método acima, apaga apenas 1 versão do arquivo solicitado, como ficaria para apagar todas as versões do mesmo ARQUIVO_GUID?

Comment: Qual a versão do EF que você está utilizando? se for EF6 você pode usar o método .RemoveRange()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

O modo que você fez só ira deletar 1 Registro (FirstOrDefault) aonde a.ARQUIVO_GUID == arquivoVersao.ARQUIVO_GUID

Para apagar todos, faça algo assim

*Fiz fora do visual studio, pode haver erros de sintaxe*

```
internal void ApagarArquivoVersao(Model.ArquivoVersao arquivoVersao)
    {
        using (var ctx = new TESTEntities())
        {
            var arquivos = ctx.ARQUIVO_VERSAO.Where(a => a.ARQUIVO_GUID == arquivoVersao.ARQUIVO_GUID).ToArray();

            if (arquivos.Length == 0)
                throw new ArquivoException("Arquivo não encontrado");

            foreach(ARQUIVO_VERSAO fileVer in arquivos){
                ctx.Entry(fileVer).State = System.Data.EntityState.Deleted;
            }
         ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu vinha tentando com o where, porem nao tava dando certo pq tinha que converter pra array, valeu.

Answer (score 1):

Se deseja apagar todas as versões de um arquivo, então é interessante ter o arquivo como parâmetro do método.

```
internal void ApagarVersoes(Model.Arquivo arquivo)
```

Quanto ao método, se estiver usando o EF5, você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
using (var ctx = new TESTEntities())
{
    foreach (var versao in arquivo.ARQUIVO_VERSAO)
    {
        ctx.ARQUIVO_VERSAO.Remove(versao);
    }
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

No EF6 é mais simples:

```
using (var ctx = new TESTEntities())
{
    ctx.ARQUIVO_VERSAO.RemoveRange(arquivo.ARQUIVO_VERSAO);
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```